# CondaVerificationError: || ClobberError: Create a new conda environment with Python 2.7.x or 3.7.x

Tags: python, machine-learning, anaconda, miniconda, graphlab

While Creating a new conda environment with Python 2.7.x or 3.7.x using 
`conda create -n gl-env python=2.7 anaconda=4.0.0` I get the following errors

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

```
CondaVerificationError: The package for bokeh located at C:\Users\kokul\Miniconda3\pkgs\bokeh-0.11.1-py27_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'Scripts/bokeh-script.py-server'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults::notebook-4.1.0-py27_2, defaults::qtconsole-4.2.0-py27_1
  path: 'menu/jupyter.ico'
```

How to solve it?

Comment: See https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/66084/88005

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because it is searching for a wrong file that doesn't exist. You can simply fix this by editing the `files` manifest file in package `bokeh-0.11.1-py27_0`

1. Go to package location. In this case `C:\Users\kokul\Miniconda3\pkgs\bokeh-0.11.1-py27_0`
2. Open the file `files` in directory `info`
3. Find string `bokeh-script.py-server` and replace it by `bokeh-server-script.py`
4. Save and try again.

Comment: More info on this: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5196

Answer (score 10):

This may be due to a failed or incomplete package install. I Fixed the problem by first.

```
conda clean --all
```

Respond with `Y`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to solve without undo and redo. I undo the action by

```
conda clean --packages --tarballs
```

and then redo by

```
conda create -n gl-env python=2.7 anaconda=4.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate option

1. install Anaconda 2
2. create an env name gl-env in environment option and proceed with rest of option