# "CondaVerificationError: path '.../iTerm.app' cannot be found." when creating conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm running Mac OS X 10.14.1 (18B75), Python 3.7.0 and conda 4.5.11. I tried to create a new environment:

```
conda create -n cv-final python pip
```

It asked to install new packages and I press 'y' to proceed, but then it threw errors:

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

CondaVerificationError: The package for ncurses located at /Users/johan/anaconda3/pkgs/ncurses-6.1-h0a44026_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'share/terminfo/69/iTerm.app'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for ncurses located at /Users/johan/anaconda3/pkgs/ncurses-6.1-h0a44026_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'share/terminfo/69/iTerm2.app'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.
```

I've tried `conda clean --packages --tarballs` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048124/condaverificationerror-clobbererror-create-a-new-conda-environment-with-pyt), but no luck.

Running

```
conda env create cv-final
```

does create a new empty environment, but trying to install packages

```
conda install -n cv-final python pip
```

will still get the same errors.

Comment: Days past. Now I don't have this problem now. I don't remember precisely how I fixed it. Maybe try updating conda.

Comment: Try these steps: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/66084/88005